# What the difference between Resolve and ResolveSibling

Tags: java, nio

I can't get the difference between two java NIO methods: resolve and resolveSibling. Please, can anybody explain it?

Comment: The documentation explains: [`Path#resolve(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) and [`Path#resolveSibling(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling(java.nio.file.Path)). The latter's documentation even gives the default implementation which should make the differences quite explicit. If that doesn't help then please [edit] your question to be more specific about what you're confused about.

Answer (score 2):

**resolve(String other)** method is used to converts a given path string to a Path and resolves it against this Path in the exact same manner as specified by the resolve method. If the name separator is “/” and a path represents **“a/b/c”**, then invoking this method with the path string **“xxx”** will result in the Path **“a/b/c/xxx”**.

**resolveSibling(String other)** method is used to resolve the given path as parameter against this path’s parent path.Suppose that the name separator is **“/”** and a path represents **“a/b/c”**, then invoking this method with the Path **“xxx”** will result in the Path **“a/b/xxx”**. If this path does not have a parent path or other is absolute, then this method returns others. If other is an empty path then this method returns this path’s parent, or where this path doesn’t have a parent, the empty path.
**This is very useful where a file name needs to be replaced with another file name.**